# DiscordJS setting welcomer to a certain channel

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.type === 'text' && ch.permissionsFor(client.user.id).has('SEND_MESSAGES'))
member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'greetings' || 'welcome')
channel.send(welcomeembed);
```

I am trying to set the my welcomer to any channel called greetings or welcome i have tried to implement it with line 2 of the example above but did not work, how would i fix this

Comment: thats what i had before it still puts the welcome in a random channel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.type === 'text' && ch.permissionsFor(client.user.id).has('SEND_MESSAGES') && ch.name === 'welcome')
if(channel) {
channel.send(welcomeembed);
}
```

fixed it

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to set the my welcomer to any channel **called** greetings or
> welcome

```
member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'greetings' || channel.name === 'welcome')
```

This should works

Comment: why? `guild.channels.cache` returns a `Collection<Snowflake, GuildChannel|ThreadChannel>`, and the `find()` method returns the first `GuildChannel` named greeting or welcome

Comment: Because first time it compares if channel name is "greetings" and second time it compares an object with a string

Comment: i have also tried  https://pastebin.com/X2hB3tdU  but nothings working

Comment: @aymcg31 You are right. I didn't noticed that.